# Lentitud usando la libreria leaflet

Tags: map, leaflet

Estoy usando la siguiente librería, simplemte estoy pintando el mapa de españa y un marcador pero la carga es muy lenta, tengo todo el codigo en local:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

¿Alguien que este probando esta libreria?

app.js

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([base.x, base.y], 12);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; 2019'
    }).addTo(mymap);
var marker = L.marker([mark.x, mark.y]).addTo(mymap);
```

index.html

```
<div id="mapid" style="height:500px"></div>
```

Comment: seria bueno que colocaras el codigo que estas usando para poder ayudarte.

Comment: he actualizado con el código que hago, gracias